# Can I write an index for an $or query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a few different but similar mongodb queries that I need to write an index for.  Is this the correct way to do it?

First Query:

```
{
    $or: [
        {_id: "..."}, 
        {linkedListingID: "..."}
    ]
}
```

Second Query:

```
{
    $or: [
        {_id: "..."}, 
        {linkedListingID: {$in: ["...", "..."]}
    ]
}
```

Third Query:

```
$or: [
    {
        _id: {$in: ["...", "..."]},
        linkedListingID: {
            $exists: false,
        },
    },
    {
        linkedListingID: {$in: ["...", "..."]},
    },
];
```

Index:

```
Listing.index(
    {
        _id: 1,
        linkedListingID: 1
    },
    {name: "index_name"}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [$or documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#behaviors),

> When using indexes with `$or` queries, each clause of an `$or` can use its own index.

That means it will not use compound index!

To support your query, rather than a compound index, you would create one index on `_id` and another index on `linkedListingID`:

```
Listing.index({ _id: 1 });
Listing.index({ linkedListingID: 1 });
```

---

For more details try [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) with your query, and check `executionStats` > `executionStages` > `inputStage`

**Explain state with compound index:**

```
Listing.index({ _id: 1, linkedListingID: 1 }, {name: "index_name"});
```

**Result:** This will scan full collection `"stage": "COLLSCAN"`!

```
    "winningPlan": {
      "inputStage": {
        "direction": "forward",
        "filter": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "_id": {
                "$eq": "abc"
              }
            },
            {
              "linkedListingID": {
                "$eq": "bca"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "stage": "COLLSCAN"
      },
      "stage": "SUBPLAN"
    }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oujYwpCupWo)

**Explain state with single index:** Here `_id` not needed index because by default `_id` having unique index,

```
Listing.index({ linkedListingID: 1 });
```

**Result:** this will at least use index individually `"stage": "IXSCAN"`!

```
    "winningPlan": {
      "inputStage": {
        "inputStage": {
          "inputStages": [
            {
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "_id": [
                  "[\"abc\", \"abc\"]"
                ]
              },
              "indexName": "_id_",
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isUnique": true,
              "keyPattern": {
                "_id": 1
              },
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "_id": []
              },
              "stage": "IXSCAN"
            },
            {
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "linkedListingID": [
                  "[\"bca\", \"bca\"]"
                ]
              },
              "indexName": "_linkedListingID",
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isUnique": false,
              "keyPattern": {
                "linkedListingID": 1
              },
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "linkedListingID": []
              },
              "stage": "IXSCAN"
            }
          ],
          "stage": "OR"
        },
        "stage": "FETCH"
      },
      "stage": "SUBPLAN"
    }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xTdYZHiBd2P)

Answer (score 1):

By default, MongoDB creates a **unique index** on the [_id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) field during the creation of a collection.

You query could be as simple as:

```
{_id: "..."}
```

MongoDB ensures that the indexed fields do not store duplicate values; for that reason you query on the _id will alway retrieve an unique document.